# How to post message to Facebook through Parse SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I've done some work to register/login to a Facebook account through Parse SDK ([this](http://www.thezeusoft.com/parse-loginregister-facebook-login-demo/) is what I did). The next step is to post some messages to Facebook in my application. But I encountered a problem.

When the app logged in, only "user_about_me" and "user_location"] permissions are granted. So I need to reauthorize the user when he's trying to post something. Here is the code:

```
// if user is linked to Facebook (login to Facebook), then
if let session = PFFacebookUtils.session() {

    let array = session.permissions as NSArray                            
    if array.indexOfObject("publish_actions") == Int(Foundation.NSNotFound) {

        let permissionsArray = [ "publish_actions" ]
        PFFacebookUtils.reauthorizeUser(PFUser.currentUser(), withPublishPermissions: permissionsArray, audience: FBSessionDefaultAudience.Everyone, block: { (success, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil && success {
                self.postToFacebook(comment.comment)
            }
        })
    } else { 
       self.postToFacebook(comment.comment)
    }
 }

func postToFacebook(message : String) {

    var postParams =
        ["https://developers.facebook.com/ios" : "link",
        "https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/iossdk_logo.png":"picture",
        "Facebook SDK for iOS":"name",
        message: "message",
        "Build great social apps and get more installs.":"caption",
        "The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps." : "description",
        ];

    let req = FBRequest(session: PFFacebookUtils.session(), graphPath: "me/feed", parameters: postParams, HTTPMethod: "POST")
    req.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            println("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            println("posted to facebook")
        }
    }    
}
```

The app did redirect me to Facebook page when I was trying to post something:

[image]

But it ended up with a few errors, inside the **userInfo** in error object:

> [0]   (null)  @"com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey" : (no summary)
>   [1](http://www.thezeusoft.com/parse-loginregister-facebook-login-demo/)   (null)  @"com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey" : (no summary)
>   [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jr0xP.png)   (null)  @"com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode" : (long)200

I think the error is still related to permissions because the app redirected to Facebook for authorization everytime when I'm trying to post something.But I'm not very sure.What could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: Are you redirected or are users redirected?

Comment: It will be redirected automatically.

Comment: Based on the document of Facebook, I may need to ask for the review for the permission of "publish_actions", is that true?

Comment: Yes, I think that you need to add those permissions in the Facebook app console.